# Why does decorator work like that?

Tags: python-2.7, python-decorators

I try to figure out the meaning of **decorator** in python, and practice a snippet as below on python console:

```
def print_my_name(name):
    print "I am %s" %(name())

@print_my_name
def my_name():
    return "Hans"
```

And it will come out with,

> I am Hans

It never happens on normal functions.
Could anybody tell me how it works?

Thank you

Comment: What you want to know?

Comment: @Shivkumar Kondi actually I didn't call my_name(), but it still work automatically. How come?

Comment: I have updated my answer. If possible you can read it in breif  here ..https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator

Answer (score 1):

A decorator takes the function definition and creates a new function that executes this function and transforms the result.

The shortest explanation that I can give is that decorators **wrap** your function in another function that returns a function.

This code, for example:

```
@decorate
def foo(a):
  print a
```

would be equivalent to this code if you remove the decorator syntax:

```
def bar(a):
  print a

foo = decorate(bar)
```

Decorators sometimes take parameters, which are passed to the dynamically generated functions to alter their output.

Another term you should read up on is **closure**, as that is the concept that allows decorators to work.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I do know what decorator is. But I wonder why it gives an output directly without any invocation after I finish typing and hit "Enter".

Comment: @user3893952 Understand that calling mechanism of decorated. That's why I have mentioned a link above in comment

Comment: OK, I got your point. Actually, foo = decorate(bar) does the trick behind the scene. Thanks,

Comment: @user3893952 Welcome dude!